# sidebar menu doesnt show up Yii

Tags: php, yii

I've been trying now for an hour to figure out how $this->menu works in Yii views. I found that you just put this in view file of controller and it should work, but for me it doesnt appear on web page.

```
$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'create', 'url'=>'/create/')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your default layout used in controller for example:

```
public $layout='//layouts/column2';
```

You will find this in `{appdir}/views/layouts/column2.php` path.
In this template you need to have this where you want to show the custom menu:

```
<?php
    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
        'title'=>'',
        'hideOnEmpty'=>true,
    ));
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
        'items'=>$this->menu,
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
    ));
    $this->endWidget();
?>
```